# Using application classes as utilities in unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, anti-patterns

This is a question about best practices for unit tests. Let's say I have a `ClassA` that does some object transforms (from CSVs to Java beans, using external library). Then I have `ClassB` that needs these transformed Java beans to execute a calculation. 
When writing a unit test for `ClassB`, is it acceptable to use `ClassA`'s transform method to get these transformed bean objects? In other words, use an application class as utility in unit test.

The other option would be to write a util test method which would have same code as `ClassA` (the transformation is done using an external library, so it's easy to use it in both application class and test utility class)

Comment: App uses the transformation method, so use the app transformation method. Separate method in Unit tests could not fulfill the requirements in time, where the class responsible for transforming always will be aligned to the requirements.
TL;DR you already have class that has methods which transforms the data, don't write new ones.

Comment: I would test ClassB with bean types directly instead of starting with CSV data. You could simply mock the bean types, but if that is not acceptable and if there is no other way than to create beans using ClassA, I would use ClassA to create the ClassB test-inputs as you are suggesting. I would not duplicate the code in ClassA in the ClassB test class.

Comment: and there's your answer :) Mock the beans that are going to be used in calculations, because for ClassB you want to only check if it calculates the data properly. Probably the test which would firstly transform CSV to beans and then calculate is an integration test (but I'm not sure about the corect naming of this type of test).

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about best practices - thus I will not answer for your particular example (for which others have already given you some hints how to handle it), but I will look at the general question: Is it acceptable to use application classes as utility classes within test code.

There can be situations where this is the design alternative which is the best tradeoff between all goals, but it depends on the specific situation.  The competing goals are the following:

- Avoiding code duplication, test code readability: Creating complex objects from test code can make the test code complex and maintenance intensive.  Re-using other application code to create these objects can simplify the test code, which otherwise would somehow duplicate the code for object creation.
- Trustworthiness of the test code: If your test code depends on other components, the test results become less trustworthy - failing tests may be due to the other components, passing tests can be due to the created objects having different properties than intended in the test. Note that the risk of this happening can be reduced if the functions used as utilities are themselves thoroughly tested.
- Completeness of the test suite: When using utility functions to create input objects there is a risk that only those input objects are used during tests that the utility functions are able to create.  That is, if the utility functions will never create malformed objects, then you might limit your testing such that you never test your SUT with malformed objects.  If you are aware of this risk, you can certainly still have some additional tests where malformed objects are used - in these tests you can, however, not use the utility functions.
- Complexity of the test setup, execution time etc.: If the utility functions themselves have further dependencies, or they compile, link or execute slowly, they bring all these disadvantages into the test code.  Thus, only certain application functions will be suitable to be used in test code.

An example that comes to my mind is testing some function that receives a parse tree of an algebraic expression as input and shall evaluate that expression.  Assume that the same application also has a parse function that creates parse trees from strings.

Using the parse function within unit-tests of the evaluation function would IMO be a good option here: The expression strings would be nicely readable in the unit-tests, the parse function will likely only have dependencies that the test code would otherwise need by itself anyway (like, classes for nodes and edges of the parse tree).  The parsing can be expected to have no significant impact on test performance.  Plus, if the parse function is well tested its use within the test code will not impact the trustworthiness in a significant way.  It may nevertheless still be necessary to have some extra tests where malformed parse trees are intentionally created to test the behaviour of the evaluation function for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

when you unit test a method

- you prepare the data ( mocks, hardcoded etc ),
- you call the method under test
- you evaluate the result

what you do not do is call other things, utility methods etc.

Why?

Because that means that your code has dependencies on other things and it does not run in isolation.

It also means that your test has too much knowledge about the code and that's a bad things especially when you start doing refactoring. Too much knowledge about the code means that as soon as you change the code you will break most tests which defeats one of of their purposes which is to make refactoring ( and developers life ) easier.